# How to get image url from tweets using the Twitter API

Tags: image, url, twitter

I'm using this code:

```
require_once ("twitteroauth.php");

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'XXX');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'XXX');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'XXX');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'XXX');

$toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

$query = array(
  "q" => "#Misiones",
  "result_type" => "recent",
  "include_entities" => "true"
);

results = $toa->get('search/tweets', $query);

foreach ($results->statuses as $result) {

  $user = $result->user->screen_name;
  $text = $result->text;
```

To get tweets whit the hashtag #Misiones(the name of the place where i'm live). Works fine but i'm trying to get the image url (if the tweet have some).
I tryed with $result->media and $result->media->media_url and other convinations without succcess.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Tweet Entities](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object.html#media) are what you are looking for to access the pictures. Entities provide structured data from Tweets including expanded URLs and media URLs. They are located under the `entities` attribute in all Tweet objects from both Twitter REST and Streaming APIs.

As a result, to answer your question, if a Tweet contains one picture, its URL will be located here:

```
$media_url = $result->entities->media[0]->media_url;
```

Below is a PHP snippet you can add to your existing `foreach` loop, it is a bit more elaborate to handle whether or not the Tweet contains media URLs:

```
if (isset($result->entities->media)) {
    foreach ($result->entities->media as $media) {
        $media_url = $media->media_url; // Or $media->media_url_https for the SSL version.
    }
}
```

Comment: link to tweet entities is dead as of 20171128

Comment: I believe the new link to the Tweet Entities doc may be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object).  For completeness, I believe Twitter suggests using extended entities for native media (which I believe fits the scope of this question), and that document may be viewed [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/extended-entities-object).

Answer (score 18):

To get the media_url back to twitter search pass `tweet_mode=extended`. Works across multiple endpoints (eg. /statuses/show, /statuses/user_timeline ..)

Example: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=aneon&tweet_mode=extended`

More here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates.html

Answer (score 10):

To get the image url of a Tweet with the new v2 api you must append `expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=url` at your url.
For example to open a stream that returns tweets with their images(if any) create a get request like this

`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=created_at&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=url`

Answer (score 0):

To get an image url of a tweet, you need a tweet object and a media object. The media object can be obtained with a tweet id.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/media